# Is this a sufficient condition for vertex and edge transitivity?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm traying to prove (or disprove) the following statement:

Any connected $r$-regular graph of [girth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_%28graph_theory%29) $g$ such that every edge is shared by the same number of minimum length cycles (that is, cycles of length $g$), is [vertex-transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph) and [edge-transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-transitive_graph).

This is not a textbook exercise. Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The statement is false if the graph can be disconnected.  A connected (4,4)-graph can be constructed by drawing a grid on the torus.  Consider the disjoint union of two such graphs with different numbers of vertices.

Comment: @JeffE Of course you're right. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is also false for connected graphs.

For instance, if you take the pentagonal prism (it is vertex transitive but not edge transitive) you can then form a graph as follows: replace each vertex by a triangle then identify vertices which are joined by an edge.

[image: Not transitive]

This graph is 4-regular and of girth 3 and every edge is in exactly one triangle.

However it is not vertex or edge transitive; 
 10 vertices are part of 5-cycles without chords but 5 vertices aren't. 
 Some edges lie in a 4-face and some don't.

Comment: Thanks. That disproves it.

Comment: when you say "Some edges lie in a 4-face ...", you mean "... 4-cycle", right?

Comment: yes, there are no 4-cycles which aren't 4-faces in this planar graph though since every edge lies in exactly one triangle